# SlideUp/SlideDown not quite working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to toggle an element:

```
function toggle(elemName) {
    text = document.getElementById(elemName);
    var isHidden = text.style.display == 'none';
    text.style.display = isHidden ? 'block' : 'none';

    if (text.style.display == 'none') {
        $(text).slideUp();
    }
    else {
        $(text).slideDown();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Really what I need is, if it is hidden, slide down, if it is visible, slide it up and make it disappear.

It is hiding and showing but the sliding does not work.

What could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: how exactly are u going to see a slideup if the display is none ?

Comment: also you could use Jquery to check visibility like this :

var visible = $("element").is(":visible");

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding element before calling `slideUp()` or `slideDown()`.

Remove this line and it should work fine:

```
text.style.display = isHidden ? 'block' : 'none';
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: How do I then determine if it is hidden to slide up or down?

Comment: slideUp and slideDown takes care of this :). Calling slideDown adds `display: none;` to element calling it :)

Comment: see my answer  user2043533

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function customToggle(elemId) {
    var elem = $('#'+elemId);

    if ( elem.is(':visible') ) { elem.slideUp(); }
    else { elem.slideDown(); }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    customToggle('myId');
});
```

and note that in your example `$(text).slideUp();` won't work, because text will return id name only, like this: `$('myId').slideUp();` and it should be like this in jQuery: `$('#myId').slideUp();`

Answer (score 0):

Will slideToggle suit your needs?

```
function toggle(elemName) {
    text = document.getElementById(elemName);
    $(text).slideToggle();
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/kmd97/heVEE/

Answer (score 0):

See working demo http://jsfiddle.net/CAeSD/4/

You had your logic backwards, use `!= 'none'` not `== 'none'`.

Also REMOVE your lines that say this:

```
var isHidden = text.style.display == 'none';
text.style.display = isHidden ? 'block' : 'none';
```

So the **WORKING CODE** is as follows:

```
function toggle(elemName) {
    text = document.getElementById(elemName);

    if (text.style.display != 'none') {
        $(text).slideUp();
    }
    else {
        $(text).slideDown();
    }
    return false;
}

$("#name").on('click', function(){
                  toggle("txt");
});
```